# System.Data.SqlTypes and NULL

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

If I have a variable, X, of type SqlDecimal, that was instantiated without providing a decimal value parameter to the constructor, then the .IsNull property is True:

```
Dim X As New SqlDecimal '.Value = Null
```

If I have a Stored Procedure that acepts a single parameter, @SqlDecimalParameter, of type Decimal, the value of this this parameter could be NULL or a decimal value. This is how I would normally call the stored procedure:

```
Dim Cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

 If X.IsNull Then
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter(parameterName:="@SqlDecimalParameter", value:=DBNull.Value))
Else
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter(parameterName:="@SqlDecimalParameter", value:=X.Value))
End If
```

However, I would expect the following to work, but it does not when the X.IsNull is true.

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter(parameterName:="@SqlDecimalParameter", value:=X))
```

It seems like the 1st example should work. Am I missing something? after all, the Sql datatypes are designed to work with SQL Server, I thought.

When X is set to the following

commissionDue = New SqlDecimal(3.2)

I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlDecimal to a Decimal
```

It works when X.IsNull is True.

How do *you* set the value of the PARAM object when it can be NULL?

Comment: What exception are you getting, btw?

Comment: I thought I was getting an error that was something like SqlDecimal could not be converted to a Decimal, but now the damn thing seems to be working. I swear the thing is inconsistant. It must be me. I'm investigating. Are you agreeing that it sounds like the 2nd approach should work?

Comment: Ah-I reproduced it. Plz check my updated post.

Comment: Did you mean to say "If Not X.IsNull" then add a param object, otherwise don't and, as a result, Null will be passed? If so, that sounds like a better way of doing it, but still it seems longer than necessary/than the way I expected it to work, which required no if. Good suggestion.

Comment: Nope, not passing the parm if it is NULL doesn't work: Procedure or function 'UpdateCustomerPerformance' expects parameter '@commissionDue', which was not supplied

Answer (score 1):

First idea:
You need to **specify the type explicitly** when creating a new instance of a parameter. Otherwise the framework will try to infer the type, which is never something you should count on going the right way.

```
Dim parameter As New SqlParameter("@SomeName", SqlDbType.[Decimal])
parameter.Value = 3.2
```

Second idea:
Instead of creating a SqlDecimal value try using a **simple nullable decimal**. This way it does not have to be converted and you might be able to avoid the error.

```
Dim test As System.Nullable(Of Decimal) = 3.2
```

Comment: How do you set Test to Null? Test = Nothing? Pretty sure that is how...When I do that I get: Procedure or function 'UpdateCustomerPerformance' expects parameter '@commissionDue', which was not supplied.<BR>

Comment: I did specify the type, sorry for not including it in my example.

Comment: So the second one works with an actual value (3.2) but not with a null value? Try to additionally specify on construction that the parameter is nullable.

Comment: No, it worked with the NULL value, but could not convert the SqlInt32 object to an int. how do I specify that the *PARAM* is NULLABLE?

Comment: There is another constructor overload that takes an additional boolean flag to signal the parameter that its nullable.